# Catching all exceptions in order to debug more easily once my application is deployed

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Novice programmer here. I'm phrasing this question in terms of Python, but I think it makes sense for any programming language that has the concept of Exception Handling.

Here it is: I'm writing a software for a business client, who will interact with the software by using a GUI.

I'm thinking about putting all of the core business logic in a `try`/`except` block in order to catch all exceptions that I haven't planned for (and which I catch and resolve before they bubble up). These could be bugs in other libraries that I'm using, my own bugs, or other unforeseen events. The output of those exceptions I want then to display in a GUI error message.

The reasoning behind this will be that if such an error were to occur once my software is deployed and the client would call me telling me "hey, I got this error message that says X", then I would have at least some hint from X as to what went wrong and could immediately start debugging - rather then the GUI just exiting silently and the client calling me and telling "your app just died".

1) Would this be a good idea? Since this software will be used in a "safe setting" there is no issue of sensitive information leaking into the error message, which then is displayed. But I'm still unsure, of there aren't any other problems I might run into with this approach.

2) If I should go down this route, should I use `except BaseException` or `except Exception`?
Even after consulting [Python's exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) I don't really get when the three additional exceptions that I'd get if I were to use the first option are really thrown. My application won't use the keyboard, so I *think* I'm safe regarding `KeyboardInterrupt`, but I'm unsure about the other two,`SystemExit` and `GeneratorExit`.

Comment: 1. no, do not show unfiltered Exception mesages to users -- You should learn about [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html). Then you can log the exception with the stack trace in your all-enclosing except. That way, you can look it up in your log and only you get to see the code internals.

Comment: Maybe this would be useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook

Comment: @schwobaseggl So you are saying it is better to show the client a generic error message and then generate a file containing the logging output and ask the client to send me that file? (The application is not connected to the internet.)

Comment: @warvariuc I did not knew about that! Thanks!

Comment: No further clarification?...

Answer (score 0):

1. Show the error messages in your gui *only if the user needs to know*, such as when the program cannot recover from an error.
2. Use `except BaseException` to avoid catching exceptions that need to be handled differently. If you need to catch every single type of exception, try to make as many `except` blocks as possible in order to recover from as many errors as possible.

Comment: Regading 1: Since I only show those exceptions verbatim which I did not catch before they bubble up, I guess I'm already doing what you wrote?        $$$$
Regarding 2: I think you mean `except Exception` or something higher in the hierarchy?  Since `BaseException` would not avoid catching exceptions that need to be handled differently, it would catch everything. Or am I not getting something here?

Comment: @l7ll7 by `except BaseException`, I mean if you have a hierarchy of exceptions you want to catch, `BaseException` is the base of the hierarchy. You should usually handle each exception individually instead of adding a `except Exception`.